# How to join multiple tables into one

Tags: c#, sql, database

How do I join multiple tables into one?

I have 3 Datatables with column names: `Test 1, Test 2 and Test3`

The Datatables got 3 rows with values.

I want them in one datatable like the example below

```
TEST 1  |  TEST2  |  TEST 3
```

I've tried the merge function `dt1.merge(dt2)` but it adds additional 3 rows to every column.

The table is for `DataGridView`.

This is the code example on how i retrieve the table from the database.

```
            string queryStatusTest =
               "SELECT status AS 'uppgift " + t +"' FROM b_personuppgift
                        WHERE uppgiftid IN(SELECT uppgiftid FROM b_uppgift
                                                   WHERE kursid = 'ABC123') "
                  + "AND uppgiftid=" + t + " ORDER BY uppgiftid";
            DataTable dTest = dataBase.Select(queryStatusTest);
```

The `database.Select()` function returns only one table.

Comment: u have 3 different databases or 1 database with 3 tables as Test 1, Test 2 and Test3??

Comment: I have 1 database, the tables comes from SQL queries, i updated my question now. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: do you need a JOIN or an UNION?

Comment: Why Merge method does not work? *it adds additional 3 rows to every column.* is not what you expect? what is your expected result?

Comment: sorry my bad, it is an UNION that i need, can it only be done with SQL queries ? or is it possible to do it with some coding in csharp with my 3 DataTable.

Comment: Does the DataTables have a primary key set?

Comment: Yes.

The columns in the b_personuppgift are PersonUppgiftID, UppgiftID, Name, Status and Points. PersonUppgiftID is the primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume 3 columns type are string:

```
var mergeTable = dt1.AsEnumerable()
     .Concat(dt2.AsEnumerable())
     .Concat(dt3.AsEnumerable())
     .GroupBy(row => new { 
                        Test1 = row.Field<string>("Test1")
                        Test2 = row.Field<string>("Test2") 
                        Test3 = row.Field<string>("Test3") 
                        })

     .Select(g => g.First())
     .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: I dont understand where the "row" and "g" variable comes from.

Comment: It's part of the [LINQ lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). The "row" represent the element currently processed and "g" is the group currently processed. They could be renamed anything.

Comment: It says Column 'Test2' does not belong to table, but im pretty sure the column name on dt2 is Test2.

Comment: @user1693991: Test2 does not belong to dt1 and dt3?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that saying **database** you mean **table**. You can insert data from all 3 tables into one using this statement:

```
INSERT INTO table_all(column1,column2,column3) 
VALUES( 
  (SELECT column1 FROM test1),
  (SELECT column1 FROM test2),
  (SELECT column1 FROM test3),
)
```

Comment: Why? He mentioned he wanted the data in one database (well.. table really) and he tried to achieve this by merging. Views should be read-only.

Comment: Because he want most probably only display them instead of copy creation.

Comment: Even though it became clear later that the user wants to only display data I wouldn't use a view for such a simple thing...

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for this problem is that you haven't set the primary key on the DataTables. The Merge method uses the primary key to match rows.

The [Merge method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx) in MSDN states:

> When merging a new source DataTable into the target, any source rows
>   with a DataRowState value of Unchanged, Modified, or Deleted, is
>   matched to target rows with the same primary key values. Source rows
>   with a DataRowState value of Added are matched to new target rows with
>   the same primary key values as the new source rows.